# please explain how to implement main method in my code?

Tags: java, methods

Please explain how to implement main method. i am having trouble with the main method and the line after main method, why the line after main method showing illegal start of expression?? is it because i forgot to put bracket somewhere or my code is wrong?? the code is suppose to perform arithmetic with fraction.

public class Rational{

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    public int numerator;
    public int denominator;

public Rational(int numerator, int denominator)

{
    this.numerator = numerator;
    this.denominator = denominator;
    reduce();
}

public Rational add(Rational other)
{
    int num = numerator * other.denominator + other.numerator * denominator;
    int den = denominator * other.denominator;
    return new Rational(num, den);
}

public Rational subtract(Rational other)
{
    int num = numerator * other.denominator - other.numerator * denominator;
    int den = denominator * other.denominator;
    return new Rational(num, den);
}

public Rational multiply(Rational other)
{
    int num = numerator * other.numerator;
    int den = denominator * other.denominator;
    return new Rational(num, den);
}

public Rational divide(Rational other)
{
    int num = numerator * other.denominator;
    int den = denominator * other.numerator;
    return new Rational(num, den);
}

private void reduce()
{
    int min = 0;
    if(numerator > denominator)
    {
        min = denominator;
    }
    else
    {
        min = numerator;
    }

    for(int i = min; i > 1; i--)
    {
        boolean isNumDiv = numerator % i == 0;
        boolean isDenDiv = denominator % i == 0;

        if(isNumDiv && isDenDiv)
        {
            numerator = numerator / i;
            denominator = denominator / i;
            break;
        }
    }
}

public String toString()
{
    return numerator + " / " + denominator;
}
```

} }

Comment: Please add the tag for what programing language you are using.

Comment: The lack of effort shown here is *amazing*.

Comment: Please, be more clear. What your code is supposed to do? In this snippet your main method seems to be empty and you seem to declare global fields inside it. Try to elaborate more your question so we can help you.

Comment: i'm sorry, i thought i shouldn't put whole code and make the question too big, i will fix my question, thanks for commenting though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have to create a program that prints a sum. You can create a file Sum.java with the Sum class inside it. Like this:

```
public class Sum {
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Sum(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int sumMyNumbers() {
        return x + y;
    }

}
```

Now you can create a file named Main.java with your Main class that will be the entry point of your program and it could be like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // It will print the number 4 on your console
        System.out.println(new Sum(2, 2).sumMyNumbers());

        // Or like this:
        Sum mySum = new Sum(2,2);
        System.out.println(mySum.sumMyNumbers());

        // Or even like this:
        int i = new Sum(2, 2).sumMyNumbers();
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

So your first mistake is that you are putting everything inside your main method.